# Firebase Notifications - User segment works, single device does not (android OS)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm working with Firebase Cloud Messaging (for push notifications).  I'm trying to send to a native Android client (android simulator).

I have the Firebase client integrated so that I'm getting the device token. It's posting up to my server and I'm storing it fine in my database. I've matched what is in the DB to what I'm outputting to the console in Android Studio, both are the same.

When I send a notification via the Firebase Console and select ***User Segment*** (and choose my app from the drop-down), the notification shows up instantly on my test client as expected.

I tried sending a json-encoded POST request via Firebase's Web API and got what seemed to be a successful response.

Request (device token masked.  priority in there from some iOS thread I read and has been tested without it):

> {"to":"fKztL______WzGZxTjRNZj2YXrOTJpGQwKodf1Mp8-edBZoeZ4VysaRAtnM7QyTMZ9JMS","priority":"high","notification":
>   {"title":"Portugal vs. Denmark","body":"5 to 1"}}

Response:

> {"multicast_id":4910502640920269865,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":>0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1476243679500399%3afa7e613afa7e61"}]}

For some reason, the notification never showed up. I tried pasting the device token into Firebase Console and sending from there. No luck either.

So for some reason, the User Segment works, but the device token id doesn't work from either the Web API or the console.  In all cases, I have the app in the background so that the notification should go to the bar at the top.

I'm catching the `onTokenRefresh()` and looking out for any changes, so I don't think I have a stale token that I'm using.

Out of curiosity - does the Firebase client handle registering the device token on the Firebase server automatically?  I'm not doing anything to send it to Firebase myself, I assume they take care of it.

My console looks weird in that it's saying no active users (I'm only running 1 copy in simulator so I don't expect much). Also, the *Notifications Funnel* chart in the Firebase Console shows that 0 copies of the message are sent/opened even though my client is getting the ones sent to user segment. It appears Firebase doesn't know my simulated client exists at all. Weird.

Also, I never did anything with a dev/sandboxed environment that Firebase specified. I'm assuming everything is just "live" in whatever production environment they provide and there aren't any stages to deploying this functionality on their servers.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

**Edit**: Just as I hit submit to post this, they showed up in the simulator (all at the same time). Any idea why they took more than 30 mins to arrive? There's no way that's reliable enough for what I'm looking to use this for. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If it's any help now, messages sent without the console will not be counted / show up in the analytics for your app in firebase.